# Angular Material Fixed Sidenav formatting trouble

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to create a SPA where I have a fixed sidenav that has routes to all the pages in my app.
I generated the sidenav like this:
`ng generate @angular/material:material-nav`

In addition I have a few pages among them I generated the dash and table schematics with these commands:

`ng generate @angular/material:material-dashboard`
`ng generate @angular/material:material-table`

Currently (after a lot of tinkering with CSS) I am not able to find a responsive solution to not having the sidenav overlap with my content, here is a picture of how it looks now (when not putting in set margins which mess up the responsiveness):

[image: Screenshot of my app]

Comment: Please post actual code, or ideally a working example on Stackblitz or similar. Screenshots can't be debugged.